# apigility installation and accessing

Tags: php, webserver, shared-hosting, laminas-api-tools

I have a shared Hosting Server and I want to install apigility.

It's already installed but I don't know how I can access it because the route to `it is http://0.0.0.0:8080`.

Now I don't know what I should do to get the access to the localhost address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so simple
You can try it

```
http://yourwebsite.com/public/apigility/ui#/
```

if You are facing any issue , please ping me i will guide you